# strip text within certain paramaters in any language that has a good free IDE for OSX

Tags: unix, ide, sed

I have a txt file that I want to sort of 'grep' through and get rid anything between and including '&lt' and '&gt'.  i am using osx so if you want to recommend a good, free IDE, or if I can just do it with emacs and probably already have a compiler of some sort on the OS.  so, I am looking for the script mainly, in whatever language. ReplaceAll("&lt*&gt",""), something like that? Is that java or what?

Comment: The `&lt;` and `&gt;` notation is used in HTML (and XML) to represent `<` and `>`, which are used rather extensively in HTML and XML around tags.  You'll also see `&amp;` for `&`.

Comment: Finding a "good free IDE for OSX" and running search-and-replace in a single file are two completely different goals. This has very little to do with an IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sed for this. Try `sed "s/&lt[^>]*&gt//g" file.html`

That will replace all occurrences of `&lt[^>]*&gt` (which is a basic regular expression for all text between `&gt` and )

For more details, see:

- http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed

Comment: gotta install sed, doesnt come on osx bash, suprisingly

Comment: errors when i try to use:  subnetfile:Desktop subnetfile$ sed ’s/&lt[^>]*&gt//g’ zzzOtherDescriptions.txt 
[6] 12544
[7] 12545
-bash: lt[^>]*: command not found
-bash: gt//g’: No such file or directory
[5]   Exit 1                  sed ’s/
[7]-  Exit 127                lt[^>]*
sed: 1: "’s/": invalid command code ?

Comment: Try using proper quotes (like "")

Comment: You did. My answer had incorrect quotes before, so I fixed them.